# Best way to do multiple left outer excluding joins

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I have one table that I need to bump against multiple tables with left outer joins excluding the right(s).  Is there a best practice for this? Union all the other tables first? Something else?

Here's the first thought that comes to my mind to handle this, but I want to know if there is a better more efficient way.

```
select
    master_table.*
from
    master_table
left outer join
    (
        select customer_id from table_1
        union
        select customer_id from table_2
        union
        select customer_id from table_3
        union
        select customer_id from table_4
    ) bump_table
on
    master_table.customer_id = bump_table.customer_id
where
    bump_table.customer_id is null
```

Comment: I think the answer will largely depend on the the number of duplicates in `table_[1|2|3|4]`.  There is a trade-off between sorting and joining extra rows.  If there are many duplicates, it's probably best to sort first and then join fewer rows (what you have).  But if there are very few duplicates, it's better to `union all` everything, and join a few extra rows.

Comment: Relevant: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should think a NOT EXISTS would be better. It certainly better communicates the intent of the query.

```
select * from master_table m
 where not exists( select 1 from table_1 where m.customer_id=table_1.customer_id)
   and not exists( select 1 from table_2 where m.customer_id=table_2.customer_id)
   and not exists( select 1 from table_3 where m.customer_id=table_3.customer_id)
   and not exists( select 1 from table_4 where m.customer_id=table_4.customer_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic form is surely faster -  similar to the `NOT EXISTS` that @dbenham already supplied.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM   master_table m
LEFT   JOIN table_1 t1 ON t1.customer_id =  m.customer_id
LEFT   JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.customer_id =  m.customer_id
LEFT   JOIN table_3 t3 ON t3.customer_id =  m.customer_id
LEFT   JOIN table_4 t4 ON t4.customer_id =  m.customer_id
WHERE  t1.customer_id IS NULL
AND    t2.customer_id IS NULL
AND    t3.customer_id IS NULL
AND    t4.customer_id IS NULL;
```